# New RAM sticks don't work with old ones

Tags: laptop, memory, ddr2

I bought and placed an additional 2GB of RAM in my notebook. I went to the setup screen, and appears there, I added the memory (2GB + 2GB = 4GB).

When I continued to boot the notebook, the screen indicated that Windows 7 was  loading, but before the operating system finished loading, a blue screen showedd, which suggested to me that the new memory was not working (somehow).

I then used *only* the new RAM modules in my PC and to my surprise it worked again, which leads me to believe that the conflict was between the different memory sticks.

How can I be 100% sure about that?

Edit 1: The blue screen message is:

```
A problem has been detected and Windwos has beed shutdown ...

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

BLABLABLA
Technical Information:

STOP: 0x00000000A (0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000002, xFFFFF8000C0CA869)
```

Edit 2:

My Windows is 64 bits, this influences into something?

Comment: Will your laptop accept 4GB of RAM? Try swapping the RAM between sockets.

Comment: What did the blue-screen stop message say?

Comment: blue-screen stop message don't say nothing useful, just: IRQL_LESS_OR_EQUAL

Comment: Yes, my laptop accept 4GB of RAM... And i already try to swap the RAM between sockets.

Comment: Do they provide you with manuel ram settings in the bios? If they did you could try and tweak the timings , lower the divisor , get it functional, test it then, to be sure , then tune the timings completely.  The stop message screen is (sorta) useful, indicates some driver thing usually. A "resource" allocation thing for a hardware driver, getting a minor memory errors might toss that error.  If you can not adjust the ram, then your going to have to get ram that is on the "compatability list" Or just different

Comment: Could you help me do this?

Comment: may be difference between ram as ddr2 qnd ddr3.

Comment: may be difference between ram as ddr2 qnd ddr3.

Comment: Both are DDR2 .

Comment: @Richard I could try.  Make a memtest86 usb boot disk. Then Before adding the new ram, Get in the bios, Find the "auto" or SPD auto for the ram, take it off auto.  Now it should be set for the last auto it was set for (bunch of numbers cas ras).  Raise all the numbers up 1 notch. save the bios, and try the ram again (when powered off).  for the divisor part, what they show can vary, but basically if it says 800 for the ram set it to 667 or 533 instead of 800 . If it shows 400, set it for 333, this changes the "clock rate" for the ram speed based on the base speed of FSB.

Comment: I do it all using memtest86 or have to go in the BIOS setup screen? It notes that my screen setup is very poor choices. When it comes to RAM, there just get a piece of information: the quantity, that's all.

And this program here: memtest86 is only for 32bit?

Comment: Yes, you have to have a bios that allows for the ram to be tweaked, sometimes it is just hard to find, sometimes they dont provide for it, and you must get more compatable ram. .  Yes memtest86 is 32bit still does the job of testing ram outside of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to assert that you have purchased compatible memory chips involves looking up the specifications sheet (manual) of the laptop and checking that the memory modules are listed there.

You should also verify that the ram modules are configured to run at the same frequency. Alternatively, verify that the motherboard is capable of running modules with different speeds.

On the other hand, it may be a good idea to start troubleshooting the ram modules by booting a tool such as memtest86+. After performing the test, at least you will know that the chips are not spoiled. Search for this tool on superuser if you have questions.

---

Since the error occurs when the OS is booted with more memory than configured by the vendor, a (less then well informed) guess would be that windows rejects the new hardware configuration because it does not conform to the OEM licence. I'm not very knowledgeable on this subject, but in the past, I have "broken" a windows OS by moving the HDD to a new motherboard. If you care to get informed about these restrictions, start by reading [this document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/1/6A1647EE-3FC7-47F2-9AFE-470AD5E5D856/OEMSoftwareLicensingRulesandRestrictions.pdf).

Comment: I'm unable to give a more decisive answer because the question omits information such as models of the ram modules and the motherboard.