# Adding a second RAM chip to Asus U32U Laptop

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

I have an [Asus U32U](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/U32U/specifications/) laptop. The specific model is RX012D. The configuration is:

- AMD® APU E-450
- AMD A50M Chipset
- AMD Radeon® HD 6320 Built-in
- 320GB 5400RPM HDD
- Running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS  (will move to 14.04 on release)

The RAM supported as per specifications is:

> DDR3 1333/1066 MHz SDRAM, 2 x SO-DIMM socket for expansion up to 8 GB SDRAM.

I currently have one 2GB DDR3 SDRAM at 1333 MHz. I intend to purchase another 4GB for the other slot. I have explored quite a few of the available options and have settled on [G.Skill SQ DDR3 4 GB](http://www.flipkart.com/g-skill-sq-ddr3-4-gb-1-x-gb-laptop-ram-f3-10666cl9s-4gbsq/p/itmd2ryskptsmcem).

I am moderately certain that it is compatible with the motherboard and the existing RAM chip, but I would like to be sure. So, can the new RAM be expected to work with existing chip?

Should I be looking at other RAM chips? If yes, what parameters should I be looking out for?

---

Existing memory configuration:

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type memory

# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
Location: System Board Or Motherboard
Use: System Memory
Error Correction Type: None
Maximum Capacity: 2 GB
Error Information Handle: Not Provided
Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
Array Handle: 0x0026
Error Information Handle: Not Provided
Total Width: 64 bits
Data Width: 64 bits
Size: 2048 MB
Form Factor: DIMM
Set: None
Locator: A1_DIMM0
Bank Locator: A1_BANK0
Type: DDR3
Type Detail: Synchronous
Speed: 667 MHz
Manufacturer: Hynix Semiconduc
Serial Number: 32C0EB88 
Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum0
Part Number: HMT325S6CFR8C-H9 
Rank: 1
Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
Array Handle: 0x0026
Error Information Handle: Not Provided
Total Width: Unknown
Data Width: 64 bits
Size: No Module Installed
Form Factor: DIMM
Set: None
Locator: A1_DIMM1
Bank Locator: A1_BANK1
Type: Unknown
Type Detail: Synchronous
Speed: Unknown
Manufacturer: A1_Manufacturer1
Serial Number: A1_SerNum1
Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum1
Part Number: Array1_PartNumber1
Rank: Unknown
Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
```

---

Selected G Skill RAM specifications:

- DDR3-1333/PC3-10666
- SO-DIMM Memory Module
- 204-pin Configuration
- 9-9-9 CAS Latency
- Unbuffered
- 166 MHz Memory Clock Speed

Comment: Should work fine, but this question is a bad fit for SU, because it's extremely localized to your specific product specifications. Should've asked in chat.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it "is a bad fit for SU, because it's extremely localized to your specific product specifications." :)

Comment: This is just as bad fit as [this one](http://superuser.com/q/177076/137165).

Answer (score 0):

I would personally take out that 2 GB module, and get two identical DDR3 1333 MHz modules with 4 GB each to max it out. I prefer to have it all consistent across the board: same type, brand, speed, etc. It's less prone to error. They also get to age at the same rate.

So a 8 GB kit is what I would recommend. But you could get the 4 GB module from G.Skill now, and if 6 GB is not enough, you can always take out that 2 GB module and get a 4 GB module at a later time. In that case, I recommend you get the same brand and part number as the first one.

But essentially that G.Skill "F3-10666CL9S-4GBSQ" should be good to go.

Be sure to check out following questions and answers.

- https://superuser.com/q/692949/137165
- [Adding more RAM at different speeds? Will it impact performance as much as to make it worse than without adding it?](https://superuser.com/q/509738/137165)
- [Is there a rule of thumb for RAM upgrades?](https://superuser.com/q/668863/137165)
- [New RAM sticks don't work with old ones](https://superuser.com/q/426192/137165)